# base64 encode MySQL blobs in PHP without unravelling data

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to fetch a MySQL row with blobs and return it with all blobs run through `base64_encode`, without first unravelling the fetch result?

Example

```
$res = $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$resArray = array();
$resCount = 0;
if ($this->stmt->rowCount() >  0){
    foreach($res as $row){
        $columnCount = 0;
        foreach ($row as $key => $val) {                                    
            $columns = $this->stmt->getColumnMeta($columnCount);            
            if(isset($columns['native_type'])){                             
                $columns['type'] == 'blob') {                           
                    $val = base64_encode($val); 
                }
            }
            $columnCount++;
            $resArray[$resCount][$key] = $val;                          
        }   
        $resCount++;
    }           
}
return $resArray;
```

}

Comment: You could use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_to-base64 in your query

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately at 5.5